# The using of from...to

Tags: grammaticality

Can I ask about the using of "from...to"? In my text, I have two sentences like this:

> These products may **range from garment, fashion products, footwear, perfumes, cosmetics to even agro-products, vegetables, fresh fruits**...
>
> Nowadays, women no longer restrict themselves in housework, **from cooking to teaching children and taking care of the spiritual life for family members**

The first one uses "range from A to B". But there are a lot of nouns between "from...to"in both two sentences. And the general rule I found on many dictionary websites is "from A to B".

Is it acceptable to use more than two nouns in "from...to" structure? Looking forward to your answers.

Comment: Typo:  "...cosmetics to **even** agro-products, ..."

Comment: Yes, it is perfectly acceptable and common to use multiple nouns, as in your first example.

Comment: I would only add that "and" should be used: "...and cosmetics to..." as you used "and" in the second example.